# How do I keep the rotation constant with touchpad?

Tags: android, libgdx

I've got a sprite that I'm rotating with the touchpad. Only problem I'm having is that when the touchpad is not moving, the rotation stops. Even if the touchpad is at 100% Y value, if it's held still sprite rotation stops. How do I keep the rotation constant whether the touchpad is moving or not? My code is below

```
    public class RotationTest implements ApplicationListener {
   private OrthographicCamera camera;
   private SpriteBatch batch;
   private Texture texture;
   private Sprite sprite;
   Stage stage;
   public boolean leonAiming = true;

   @Override
   public void create() {      
      float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
      float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

      camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h/w);
      batch = new SpriteBatch();

      texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx.png"));
      texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

      TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 512, 275);

      sprite = new Sprite(region);
      sprite.setSize(0.9f, 0.9f * sprite.getHeight() / sprite.getWidth());
      sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);
      sprite.setPosition(-sprite.getWidth()/2, -sprite.getHeight()/2);

      stage = new Stage();
      Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

      Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));
         Texture touchpadTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/touchpad.png"));
         touchpadTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);     
         TextureRegion background = new TextureRegion(touchpadTexture, 0, 0, 75, 75);
         TextureRegion knob = new TextureRegion(touchpadTexture, 80, 0, 120, 120);
         TextureRegionDrawable backgroundDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(background);
         TextureRegionDrawable knobDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(knob);
         final Touchpad touchpad = new Touchpad(10, new Touchpad.TouchpadStyle(backgroundDrawable, knobDrawable));
         ChangeListener listener = null;
         touchpad.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            sprite.rotate(touchpad.getKnobPercentY());
         }
      });

            touchpad.setBounds(15, 15, 225, 225);
         stage.addActor(touchpad);

   }

   @Override
   public void dispose() {
      batch.dispose();
      texture.dispose();
   }

   @Override
   public void render() {      
      Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
      batch.begin();
      sprite.draw(batch);
      batch.end();
      stage.act();
      stage.draw();
   }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering a [`ChangeListener`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ChangeListener.ChangeEvent.html) on the [Touchpad](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Touchpad.html).  Its `changed` method is only invoked when something changes on the touchpad.

Instead of updating in response to an input event, you should poll the touchpad's state in your `render()` method (so each time a frame is drawn you update the rotation if the touchpad is active).

```
if (touchpad.isTouched()) {
    sprite.rotate(touchpad.getKnobPercentY());
}
```

You will probably want to scale the rotation rate so its proportional to time and not framerate.  See [`Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()`](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html#getDeltaTime%28%29).

Comment: Thanks so much for the pointer, if I'm calling stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());   will that do the trick?